# How to store certain values from service response to an array in Angular 6?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rxjs, angular6

I have a web service call which returns an array of values. I want to store some values from the response to array.

Component.ts

```
     this.data.post_data('get/data',this.dataObj,true)
     .subscribe((data:any) => { 
         this.response= data.data;

      });
```

Webservice response

```
    0: {id: 785533, name: "UK ", avg: 0.6154,…}
    1: {id: 785533, name: "Usd ", avg: 0.698,…}
    2: {id: 785533, name: "ff ", avg: 50.61598,…}
    3: {id: 785533, name: "yy ", avg: 80.61198,…}
    4: {id: 785533, name: "nn ", avg: 10.618,…}
    5: {id: 785533, name: "mh ", avg: 0.6154898,…}
    6: {id: 785533, name: "tr ", avg: 70.615482198,…}
    7: {id: 785533, name: "es ", avg: 0.61548,…}
```

I need to save only 'name' and 'avg' values to array.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: same as response array with only needed values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate a new array with the selected fields:

```
let result = this.response.map(x => { 
  return { name: x.name, avg: x.avg };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    this.response = [];

    this.data.post_data('get/data',this.dataObj,true)
     .pipe(map(result => { return { "name": result.name, "avg": result.avg } } ))
     .subscribe((data:any) => { 
         this.response.push(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the response from the service, you can use it as you like.
If you wish to create new array with name and avg values only you can do so using many ways. You can simply iterate through the response array and assign only the desired properties to the new object of the targeted Array.